# I am inheriting 1,000,000 shares of Oklahoma Energy Corp stock ; is it worthless OKOK stock or hopefully ONEOK or OGE stock ? Is OKOK 100% worthless?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-split, nasdaq, penny-stocks

Am inheriting 1,000,000 shares of Oklahoma Energy Corp Company Stock ; is this likely worthless OKOK stock - or - valuable publicly traded ONEOK or OGE stocks ?

Comment: do You have a paper certificate? or are the shares held in a brokerage account?

Answer (score 10):

If you aren't sure, strangers on the Internet definitely can't tell you for sure.

My educated guess is: given that ONEOK and OGE are trading at around $60 and $30, a million shares would be worth $60 million or $30 million. You'd probably know if you were inheriting tens of millions of dollars, so you're probably not. It's probably the worthless OKOK.

Is this from a relative you're aware of, or an unexpected cold contact? If it’s unexpected, it may just be a scam - be very cautious about providing any personal information to whoever is contacting you.

Comment: +1000 on that last question. If it isn't the worthless paper, and you haven't previously had a relationship with this person, this screams scam.  Maybe even if you did have that relationship. Please be careful about what information you share and what you agree to.